# Why does setting maxlength for a textarea not work with asp?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I am adding the attribute to the textbox inline, but when the page loads, that attribute is not there. I do not have this issue with text boxes that do not have the `TextMode="MultiLine"` property.

My code:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtComments" TextMode="MultiLine" CssClass="form-control" maxlength="500"></asp:TextBox>
```

When I inspect with the browser, this is what is built:

```
<textarea name="txtComments" rows="2" cols="20" id="txtComments" class="form-control"></textarea>
```

What do I need to do to set the maxlength for the textarea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to add a bit of javascript to the end of the page. Here is my solution.

```
document.getElementById("txtComments").setAttribute('maxlength', '500');
```

The result from inspecting the page showed that it took.

```
<textarea name="txtComments" rows="2" cols="20" id="txtComments" class="form-control" maxlength="500"></textarea>
```

I still don't understand why it doesn't work by setting the attribute inline.